# haveing problem getting importing tensroflow in jupyter and sypder from anaconda installation

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter, spyder

To start out I had a anaconda installation with python 3.5.2. After doing a pip tensorflow installation I got an error something like "nosetest...". I searched stackoverflow and got a suggestion to move to python 3.6.

So I uninstalled the whole of anaconda and python. Then did complete fresh install of anaconda with python 3.6.10. Did a pip install of tensforflow. launched spyder and jupyter and could not import tensorflow. However, when I issue commands from python command prompt things work fine.

So can't seem to get tensorflow to import in spypder or jupyter.

Lastly following another suggest I ran the c:/from/my/anaconda/Scripts/activate base. But that also didn't work in spyder. However in jupyter it seemed to import but then crashed on tf.**version**
with access violation.

Can you please help, I've tried many things and suggestions, can't seem to get tensorflow to work with python 3.5 or 3.6.

Thanks.

P.S. I remember using python3.5.2 sometime ago with the then tensorflow, I think version 1.1x and everything went smoothly, everything installed and imported worked beautifully.

Comment: You said you're using Anaconda and used pip to install tensorflow. That's not possible to do because conda and pip packages are binary incompatible. Furthermore, you most probably corrupted your Anaconda installation. So please remove Anaconda, reinstall it and use conda to install tensorflow.

Comment: Thanks Carlos. I have in the past and even few weeks ago done pip install of tweepy, opencv and other libraries and all work fine. Is this new or specific to just for tensorflow 2.0? As I mentioned I have even done pip install with tensorflow, after installing anaconda with python 3.5. So I don't understand.